# MS Xamarin deprecated

Tags: xamarin, deprecated

When exactly Microsoft announced that MS Xamarin mobile app development framework would be deprecated? I mean the date of the first announced plan that Xamarin would be deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this qualifies as "deprecated", but during the Build 2020 conference, Microsoft announced that Xamarin Forms will be merged into the new .NET MAUI Framework.

Here's a relevant quote from [the official blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/):

> Xamarin.Forms will ship a new major version later this year, and continue to ship minor and service releases every 6 weeks through .NET 6 GA in November 2021. The final release of Xamarin.Forms will be serviced for a year after shipping, and all modern work will shift to .NET MAUI.

Note that this quote only applies to **Xamarin.Forms**, the cross-plattform UI Framework.

The underlying technologies **Xamarin.iOS** and **Xamarin.Android**, which allow you to compile C# code to iOS and Android packages, are alive and kicking and have become an official part of .NET. The blog entry states:

> As part of our .NET unification, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android will become part of .NET 6 as .NET for iOS and .NET for Android.

Answer (score 0):

The end of support date for the current version of Xamarin.Forms (5.0), Xamarin.Android (14) and Xamarin.iOS (15) is May 1, 2024: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin